# Saving a file in OneDrive from Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, onedrive

What's the **simplest** way for an Azure Functions to save a file into OneDrive? How does authentication work from a deployed Azure Function?
To make this discussion simpler, we have a string `var content = "This is the file content"` which needs to be saved as `sample.txt` file.

What if OneDrive folder is shared with an URL (real shared OneDrive link, will be removed - https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ak7ywxppmRtB8uRKhvT1FLmNBwXNwQ) and no authentication is required?

Comment: Please have a look at uploading with REST: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/onedrive-live-sdk/dn659726(v=office.15)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) for managing files stored in OneDrive.

They have great C# examples using the `Microsoft.Graph` NuGet package. You will need to implement a mechanism of authentication however and I don't think there is a way around this. For the Graph, I'd recommend [looking at these implementations for getting authenticated for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS).

Once you've authenticated in your Function app, you should be able to get to where you need to be using the Graph APIs for OneDrive available.

- [List a user's drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#list-a-users-drives)
- [Upload or update a file in a drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)